# Local Keycloak setup returns "Error: unable to verify the first certificate" nodejs error

Tags: keycloak

Trying to use **Keycloak** as SSO running within Kubernetes cluster on minikube to authenticate demo nodejs app:

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'some secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: memoryStore
}));

var keycloakConfig = {
    "realm": "Demo-Realm",
    "auth-server-url": "https://keycloak.192.168.49.2.nip.io/auth/",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "nodejs-microservice",
    "verify-token-audience": true,
    "credentials": {
      "secret": "14de3a01-5c15-42fd-aa6a-fcc35c0961ff"
    },
    "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
    "confidential-port": 0,
    "policy-enforcer": {}
};
const keycloak = new Keycloak( { store : memoryStore }, keycloakConfig );
app.use(keycloak.middleware({
    logout: '/logout',
    admin: '/'
}));

app.get('/user', keycloak.protect('user'), function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello User");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Started at port 3000');
});
```

But getting `Access denied` page when accessing `http://localhost:3000/user` with NodeJS console error: `Could not obtain grant code: Error: unable to verify the first certificate`

I have `Demo-Realm` realm created in Keycloak with such settings:

```
nodejs-microservice client:
    Access Type: confidential
    Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:3000/*
    Authorization Enabled: ON
    Roles: [ 'user', 'admin' ]
```

No login redirects happening ([basic](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube) example works properly though). What could be the problem? How can I secure my NodeJS microservice with Keycloak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is somehow related to default self-signed certificate on Keycloak side. People recommend spending some time on obtaining proper certificate.

Can be temporary solved by muting certificate verification on NodeJS side with placing such line before api/express calls:

```js
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;
```

Comment: helps with the middleware, but does not help with keycloak.grantManager.validateAccessToken(token)